# Is there an algorithmic way to either of these two tasks in programming?

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-studio, math, computer-science

I'm doing research in math and I need to perform the following tasks:

Given an unspecified set of vectors, determine which ones can sum to identity vector (1, 1, ..., 1)

For example, consider the vectors

```
x1 = (1 0 0)
x2 = (0 1 1)
x3 = (1 0 0)
```

If you add vectors x1 and x2 together, you get `(1, 1, 1)`.

Or for a bigger example

```
x1 = (1 0 0 0)
x2 = (0 1 1 0)
x3 = (0 0 1 1)
x4 = (0 0 0 1)
```

If you add vectors 1, 2, and 4 together, you get `(1, 1, 1, 1)`.

I need an algorithm that can do this in general.

The second task... given an unspecified set of numbers, determine which ones sum to 1.

For example:

```
x1 = 0.2
x2 = 0.5
x3 = 0.6
x4 = 0.4
x5 = 0.3
x6 = 0.1
x1 + x2 + x5 = 0.2 + 0.5 + 0.3 = 1
```

But also, `x1 + x4 + x5 + x6 = 1`

I need to be able to program the computer to do one of the above tasks to further my research.

Comment: Did you tried anything??

Comment: What is stopping you from programming the computer to do either of those things? You clearly understand the problems. They're not difficult to solve by brute force. Simply enumerate all possible combinations until you find one that satisfies the goal.

Answer (score 2):

For the first task, it is a variation of the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which can be solved by dynamic programming.  The difference between the subset sum problem and your problem is that subset sum problem only have one dimension.  In your case, you need to extend its dynamic programming approach to work with multiple dimensions.

For your second task, it is identical to the subset sum problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, research...

How about starting with brute force: create all the 2^N subsets of your set, and for each such candidate make the sum, if it matches the target, store it.